# Как скомпилить прогу через GCC без требований DLL?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие ключи нужно задать для gcc и g++, чтобы они сгенерировали EXE-шник, который не будет требовать сторонних DLL (кроме системных), т.е. MSVCRT.DLL, libstdc++-6.dll и т.п.? Чтобы всё это было внутри EXE-шника?

Answer (score 4):

Для стандартных библиотек есть специальные ключи - `-static-libgcc` и `-static-libstdc++`. Для остальных нужно использовать пару из ключа `-static` и `-l<имя_библиотеки>`.

Comment: Спасибо, только от **msvcrt** так избавиться не получается.

Comment: @JinX А от `msvcrt` и не получится избавиться  - это же имплементация стандартной Си библиотеки. Так же как и от `kerenl32` и прочих системных библиотек вам не избавиться.

Comment: @zed, тем не менее, **Clang**, к примеру, компилирует код (с `printf`'ами и пр.) без **msvcrt**.

Comment: @JinX [тут](https://nullprogram.com/blog/2016/06/13/) можно почитать почему.

Comment: В целом хочу добавить, что **Clang** гораздо быстрее выводит текст на **cout**.